Component init inside ng bootstrap accordion even if closed
I'm facing an issue using ng bootstrap's accordion with components inside them.
I have an *ngFor and for each index array there is an accordion that contains a component.
The problem is, even accordions at DOM rendering are closed all components inside accordion starting their life-cycle causing https calls for each component inside each accordion.
By default i left the accordion property destroyOnHide (property of ngbAccordion) set as true but nothing.
Did someone face this problem?
Below HTML code component
settings-tab.component.html
div
  class="mt-2"
  #accordion="ngbAccordion"
  ngbAccordion
  [closeOthers]="true"
  (shown)="lastAccordionOpened = $event"
>
  <div
    ngbAccordionItem
    *ngFor="let room of rooms; let index = index"
    [ngbAccordionItem]="index.toString()"
  >
    <div ngbAccordionHeader>
      <button
        ngbAccordionButton
        [style.backgroundColor]="room.bgColorHex"
        [style.color]="room.textColorHex"
      >
        {{ room.name }}
      </button>
    </div>
    <div ngbAccordionCollapse>
      <div ngbAccordionBody>
        <app-room-settings
          [room]="room"
          (roomChanged)="roomChanged.emit()"
        ></app-room-settings>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

HTTP calls are made inside  and if I set a console.log inside the constructor there are as many console.logs as the length of the array of rooms

UPDATE:
The problem was that the accordion body content must be wrapped in an ng-template since this was not done, the content is getting rendered even when the accordion is not open.
The same method can be found in the  Official Doc Examples

First set destroyOnHide to false so that the components are destroyed.
Then you need to add trackBy so that ngFor knows which elements has changed, if not it will rerender all components.
<div
  class="mt-2"
  [destroyOnHide]="false"
  #accordion="ngbAccordion"
  ngbAccordion
  [closeOthers]="true"
  (shown)="lastAccordionOpened = $event"
>
  <div
    ngbAccordionItem
    *ngFor="let room of rooms; trackBy: trackByFn;let index = index"
    [ngbAccordionItem]="index.toString()"
  >
    <div ngbAccordionHeader>
      <button
        ngbAccordionButton
        [style.backgroundColor]="room.bgColorHex"
        [style.color]="room.textColorHex"
      >
        {{ room.name }}
      </button>
    </div>
    <div ngbAccordionCollapse>
      <div ngbAccordionBody>
        <ng-template>
            <app-room-settings
              [room]="room"
              (roomChanged)="roomChanged.emit()"
            ></app-room-settings>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

TS:
...
identify(index: number, item: any){
   return item.id; 
}
...

You have to supply and unique ID for each element, if there is no such index, you can either generate an ID, or just return the index.

There is something that doesn't convince me. Why if I set [destroyOnHide]="false" should the component be destroyed? As the docs says: "If true, the content of the accordion items body will be removed from the DOM. It will be just hidden otherwise." And by default this variable is set to true.
But main problem is, even accordion are rendered first time closed components inside them will start theit file-cycle (constructor and ngOnInit are performed). They should not be performed since accordion are closed and as docs says, content is not rendered

@FeliceAnastasio its due to the ngFor without trackBy, arrays are stored as references in javascript so when you change the values inside or swapping of values in the array, there is no way for the ngFor to know what has changed, so it rerenders the entire for loop on each change detection cycle, when you use trackby the number of renders is less because it know how to track each element in the array

I tied but nothing changes at first rendering. HTTP calls made by <app-room-settings> components are still there when accordion is rendered first time, even if accordion items are closed

@FeliceAnastasio updated my answer!

Coool man, I was too tired to see that <ng-template> in official docs. Thanks man!
